# JQuery loop through input elements inside javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JQuery so if this is a obvious question my apologies. I have  a simple form which holds some input fields. On the change-event I want to change a pre-defined array. The change event is triggered, but in this change-event I want to loop through all input-element again to fill/change an array. However the iteration doesn't work.

```
    <script>        
    jsonObj = [];
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("input[class=domain]").change(function(){
            refreshData();                                                          
        });

        $("input[class=domain]").each(function() {
            var domain = $(this).attr("name");
            var score = $(this).val();

            item = {}
            item ["domain"] = domain;
            item ["score"] = score;

            jsonObj.push(item);
        });         
    });

    function refreshData() {
        alert("Text Changed");  <<-- This line is reached.      
        $(document)("input [class=domain]").each(function() {
            //TO DO: Refresh jsonObj 
            alert(domain); /<<-- This line is not reached.
        });         
    }
</script>
```

A second question would be if it is possible to shorten this code. Now I have two separate function in the document.ready-event **Change**  and
**each** both on the input-element.

T.I.A.

Comment: Aren't you getting a `TypeError: $(...) is not a function` error in console?

Comment: You shouldn't have a space between `input` and `[class=domain]`. That will look for an element with `class="domain"` **inside** an `input` element. But `input` elements aren't containers, so they can't have any elements inside them.

Comment: So that should be `input[class=domain]` or just `input.domain`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.domain').each(function(){
    alert(domain);
})
```

use this instead of      `$(document)("input [class=domain]").each`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `.` and probably a `.find` before `.each`. Below code is what it should look like:

```
$(document).find("input[class=domain]").each(function() {
      //TO DO: Refresh jsonObj 
      alert(domain); 
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

With respect to your second question I would have shortened the code as below if the lines inside your `.each` was same as it would be in `refreshData` function:

```
jsonObj = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
    refreshData();//call once on DOM Load
    $('.domain').change(refreshData); //attach it as named function to change event
});

function refreshData() {
    //keep all this code here
    $(".domain").each(function() {
        var domain = $(this).attr("name");
        var score = $(this).val();

        item = {}
        item["domain"] = domain;
        item["score"] = score;

        jsonObj.push(item);
    });        
}
```

Comment: `$(document).find()`? RLY?

Comment: Why not..? It will work @VisioN .. I just sorted it out the way he was trying to achieve..

Comment: Sure. `$(document).find("html body div form input[class=domain]")` will probably also work. Why to write useless code?

Comment: Yea.. That's correct @VisioN Updated answer for his second question and this will achieve both the things..

Answer (score 1):

This expression is wrong for some reasons:

```
$(document)("input [class=domain]")
```

**A**. There must be no space between `input` and `[class=domain]`. This is the difference between "input that has the class `domain`"  (`input[class=domain]`) and "input that one of its sub-nodes has the class domain" (`input [class=domain]`).

**B**. In order to query inside a jQuery element you need to use the `find` method like this: `$(document).find("input [class=domain]")`. But because `document` is the root element, you can just write `$("input [class=domain]")`.

P.S

In CSS-selectors (like jQuery) there is a special syntax for searching classes, so instead you can just write `input.domain`.

So this how the line should look at last:
`$("input.domain").each...`

You can read more about css selectors [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice the space between input and the bracket.

Answer (score 1):

I have done some rectification and you can shorten it like:

```
<script>        
    jsonObj = []; // array declaration
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input.domain").change(function(){ // <----better to use a class selector
            refreshData($("input.domain")); // <----pass the object in the function                                                         
        }).change(); //<----trigger it on load to execute       
    });

    function refreshData(el) { // get the passed object in the func arg
        $(el).each(function() { // <----have a loop on it this way
            var domain = $(this).attr("name"); // extract the name on current object in collection
            var score = this.value; // get the value of the current object in iteration
            var item = {}; // declare a new object
                item["domain"] = domain; // set new prop and assign value here
                item["score"] = score; // set new prop and assign value here
            jsonObj.push(item); // now push the object in the array.
        });         
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Nice. I will try this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Strange code...

```
$(document)("input [class=domain]").each
```

Try this:

```
$("input[class=domain]").each
```

Comment: yes, my mistake. I removed (document) already, but it still doesn't work. Thanks for the reply.